# I can't install Laravel using vagrant homestead with virtualbox

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have installed Vagrant, VirtualBox and Homestead correctly, made all configurations correctly, when I try to run composer command to install Laravel on my VM using SSH I got this error :

```
[ErrorException]
mkdir(): Protocol error
```

**And here is a screenshot of the error :**
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I don't what is causing thatgr

Comment: what's your virtulabox and vagrant version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using VirtualBox version 5.0.4. Seems like this a bug of `VirtualBox`: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14563

Fixed in https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.0.5-102721-OSX.dmg

So, upgrade or downgrade your VirtualBox version.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've reverted back to 4.3.38 and it worked fine.

Comment: nice to know that. @SaifLacrimosa